# Priming a spackled drywall hole

Tags: painting, repainting, patching-drywall, primer, drywall-mud

I have filled a hole in my wall with joint compound. The hole is about 3 or 4 inches wide, and part of the drywall had ripped out. I had to fill it twice, with a lot of sanding because i just couldn’t smooth out the edges well enough. I have primed it twice with a thin layer each time, i can still see the edges where the hole was, the outline is just slightly raised. My question is, should i just paint over it and hope the paint conceals it? Would it be overkill to add a third layer of primer?

Comment: The secret of smoothing is to go big.  A 3 or 4 inch patch might need 8 to 12 inch feathering.  Paint will not conceals well, bumps will show in the right light.

Comment: @crip659 thanks for your answer. do you mean feathering the joint compound or the primer? i’ve alrdy applied 2 layers of primer over the compound so i’m afraid it might be too late for the mud. but for the primer does that mean i should just apply more and spread it further out? the middle of it shows some raised bumps if you look closely

Comment: Feathering the joint compound, if done right a 1/4 inch bump can almost disappear.  A three of four inch hole should be filled in with drywall with maybe a 1x3 backing board to hold it, not just with mud.

Comment: Save yourself a headache and fill it 2-3 times more, since twice is almost certainly going to turn out to be "not good enough" when you get paint on it.